# Why can my C program run in "git bash", but not in "cmd"?

Tags: c, postgresql, gcc, mingw, git-bash

I wrote a demo using libpq to connect to a PostgreSQL database.

I tried to connect the C file to PostgreSQL by including

```
#include <libpq-fe.h>
```

after I added the paths into system variables `I:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\lib` as well as to `I:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\include` and compiled with this command:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -m64 -I "I:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\include" -L "I:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\lib" testpsql.c -lpq -o testpsql
```

It first raised three errors, like

```
libssl-1_1-x64.dll is missing
libintl-8.dll was missing
libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll was missing
```

After I downloaded these three files and put them into `I:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\lib`, and compiled it again, it shows the error

```
The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0150002)
```

when I type `testpsql`. But if I type `./testpsql` on git bash, it works. Anyone can please tell me why?

The code that I used was the first example from [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/libpq-example.html).

Environment: PostgreSQL 12, Windows 10, MinGW64

Answer (score 3, accepted):

“Download the DLL files” sounds dangerous. From where?

I would get rid of these files again. Since you probably don't reference these libraries from your code, it must be the dependencies of `libpq.dll` and are probably found in `I:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin` (if you used the EDB installer).

The problem is probably that you the `PATH` environment variable is different in `git bash` and in `cmd.exe`, and in the latter case not all required shared libraries can be found on the `PATH`. The solution is to change the `PATH` so that it includes all DLL files the executable requires, **not** to start copying around files.

It is probably enough to include `I:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin` in the `PATH`. To resolve missing dependencies, use a tool like [dependency walker](http://dependencywalker.com/) or [this replacement](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies).

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the information. I downloaded the dll files from here: https://www.dll-files.com/libssl-1_1-x64.dll.html. I will ry to change the path

Comment: Delete those downloaded files immediately. Don't ever run executables that you downloaded from somewhere.

Comment: I deleted them!!! You are right, it runs  very well without having the three dlls. But I am so confused with the environment path. I mean, if I execute the .exe under the dictionary where .exe located, why it's relevant to the environment?

Comment: You mean "directory", not "dictionary". On Windows, the current directory is always part of the shared library path. Still, it is better to set `PATH` reasonably that to copy shared libraries to each and every directory.