# CMD cannot run .exe AND including external libraries in Codeblocks Not using build option

Tags: postgresql, cmd, mingw, codeblocks

I wrote a demo using libpq to connect to a PostgreSQL database.

I tried to connect the C file to PostgreSQL by including

```
#include <libpq-fe.h>
```

after I added the paths into system variables `I:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\lib` as well as to `I:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\include` and compiled with this command:

`gcc -I "I:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\include" -L "I:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\lib" main.c -lpq -o main` that was all fine, but when I try to execute this file in CMD, it raised three errors:

```
    libssl-1_1-x64.dll cannot be found
    libintl-8.dll cannot be found
    libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll cannot be found
```

But when I use git bash to do it, it works just fine. 
In addition, I tried to change the build oprions of my project in Codeblocks, but it failed as well. 
[image]
[image]

I posted a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59087525) here couple of days ago, they suggested me to look up into the `path`, but I checked what supposes relevant for me, now I don't know how to go steps further.

The install path of my mingw64 was `D:mingw64', these are my user variables:

[image]
[image]

and system variables:

[image]

Environment: PostgreSQL 12, Windows 10, MinGW64

Comment: HeIsThere, Items `12` through `16` of your system variables output should be removed.

Comment: @Compo were they the reason that caused the `.dll cannot be found`?

Comment: No, those paths already exist in their expanded state on lines `3` through `7`, just delete them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in the case where it is not working, your `PATH` environment variable does not contain the directory `I:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin` that contains the shared library files your executable needs.

You can use `SET` on the command line to change the environment for the current session only, but it might be better to change the environment variable permanently.

Comment: Thanks! I did so, that worked with CMD, but I still cannot build the project via Codeblocks, it still shows the error `fatal error: libpq-fe.h: No such file or directory`

Comment: But that is an entirely different problem! Not finding the shared library is a problem at runtime, not finding the header file is a problem at compile time. You should ask a different question for this.

Comment: Ok, thanks for this. I don't know if it's relavent, if I execute the file with cmd, it stops at the middle while gitbash not, do you know what can be the reason?

Comment: That's material for yet another question (if you describe what "stops in the middle" means).

Answer (score 1):

As for the the `path`, I added `I:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin` to system variables like what @Laurenz Albe suggested.

For the codeblocks build problem, I clear build options, and added `I:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\include` and `I:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\lib` to `compiler setting > search directories > complier` and `compiler setting > search directories > linker`, then it works.

[image]